# A Blog for Music.Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

I spotted https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/elu-blog-the-reboot/4519#4519 this morning, about the English Language & Usage stack Overflow having a blog.  Our familiar friend @AmericanLuke is on there!

What about us creating a blog?  It would attract people to the site, encourage discussion and allow some in depth discussion of the topics that frequently come up on the site :)

**Update 17th April:**  I'm Writing a blog post entitled 'The Craft of Learning' with the intent to have it ready by May the 5th.  If you'd like to see my notes and working so far, I've got a shared note on Evernote [here](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s129/sh/e1624373-8a88-472b-ab16-b36515109f62/65463aef93a006d762306cb3ef071c6a).

Comment: Count me in!! :D

Comment: Well, I'd love to contribute! But, I feel like I'm arriving late to the party, the cake has come out, candles have been blown out, and the cake has been taken away (and we're not allowed to have any cake anyway…) If this does get off the ground, though, I promise to blog about something I have a modicum of knowledge about...

Answer (score 12):

I think this is an excellent idea. The challenge I found is getting enough people to commit to blogging and updating.

I look after the blog for Security Stack Exchange and through the last few months it has been impossible to such to our one blog a week aim, despite a large active community,mostly because people have been very busy - so a blog needs someone to be constantly chivvying and herding folks to contribute.

Here on Music.SE we do have some people with extensive knowledge of theory, practice, technique, instruments etc so I would hope it can work here.

Step one: identify volunteers, their areas of expertise and how much time they can commit.

If that looks like it will work, we can request a blog, and get things started.

And on that note, I can write a couple of posts on playing live rock gigs, or guitar effects etc

**Couple of links** we had as discussion questions when we first built the Security blog:

- [Buy in](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/276/485)
- [Logistics](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/307/485)

Volunteers so far:

- American Luke - theory
- Alexander Troup
- Rory Alsop - live gigging, electric guitar, setting up blog
- Shevliaskovic
- aldy505
- JCPedroza - DJing, sound design, electronic music, algorithmic composition, synths, software, and their convergence with music theory, practice, and performance

**Update** 15 May 2014 - Grace Note has pointed out there will be a slight delay due to resource constraints: the SE team have obviously been working on major changes with the meta.se and meta.so split, various sites going live / merging etc etc. I will check in with Grace again soon to check expectations.

Comment: We could build up a backlog of posts before starting,  so that there are a few months of stuff ready to go :D

Comment: I have added a couple of links to the meta discussions we had to start the process on Sec.SE

Comment: We could also just have the first few blog posts highlight some of the best question and answers on the site while we build up future blog posts.

Comment: Count me in as well!

Comment: Count me too! :D

Comment: Count me in if you guys are interested in blogs about DJing, sound design, electronic music, algorithmic composition, synths, software, and their convergence with music theory, practice, and performance.

Comment: I think I might pull one together on just intonation and the 12-tone scale.  We have at least 3 highly related questions on that with excellent information that will complement each other.  Hopefully in the coming months I will be able to blog regularly.  Probably mostly on technique, practice and theory.

Answer (score 4):

Right, Let's set a date for the first blog post.  I'm happy to go first if nobody else wants to.  May 5th is what I'm thinking.  What do you reckon?

Comment: What is it going to be about?

Comment: Not sure of a topic yet. Back to basics comes to mind as a good topic to begin on.  Perhaps something which doesn't apply to just one instrument, or all about the art of learning an instrument.

Comment: Learning an instrument in general or a specific one? This one sounds interesting

Comment: The title I have is 'The Craft of Learning'.  Since ultimately it's my why for being on the site I feel it would be a great start to the blog.

Comment: Excellent - as I mentioned in [chat] I'll prep a couple too. @GraceNote has mentioned a slight delay on setting up blogs but let's get ready anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Ditto what Dr. Mayhem said. I think this is a great idea and would love to help out. I'd probably be most comfortable writing about theory, but I can try other topics as well.

Answer (score 3):

What do we need to do to start the blog?

Why aren't we doing it right now?

For example, do we need to ask on Meta.StackOverflow or email StackExchange employees? Are there other posts we should make on Meta.Music to work out how we'll run the blog before we ask for our blog?

Comment: Kevin - there is a community blogs chat room ( http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs ), and I have let GraceNote know we are planning this. Have a quick look at my answer above and the links to what we had to do last time.

Answer (score 3):

An important note is that Stack Exchange has decided to suspend creation of new blogs, as noted here:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13669/23353

We were going through a similar initiative over at Math.SE, so I figured I'd let you guys know.

(I'm posting this as an answer instead of a comment so it will bump the thread and allow more people to see this.  We'll see if it's well-received or not.)

Comment: thanks anorton!