# Music SE is graduating. Congratulations!

Tags: discussion

Music Stack Exchange has a steady flow of high quality questions and answers, and a growing number of users contributing to site health and maintenance. You're on a consistent upward trend, and the Community Team (of which I am a member) has taken notice.

### Music SE will be graduating soon. Congratulations!

You've done a great job, and you should be very proud.

---

**What happens now?**

The SE Design Team will begin drafting site designs for you. I should warn you though, the team is a bit backlogged, and it may be a couple of months before you see our designers drop by to share mockups. *Don't fret; graduation is on its way.*

In the meantime, this provides an opportunity to think about how to be an even better site as privilege thresholds increase, elections are held, and you continue to grow. In the interest of reflecting and planning ahead, I'm posing a question to the community:

### *Is there anything you'd like to see Music Stack Exchange do better?*

Weigh in below.

Comment: I think some sort of music rendering should definitely be top of the list. (Re: [this post](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/913/10938))

Comment: This is good news. I've been contributing here for what seems like ages.

Comment: Hooray! This is brilliant news!

Comment: Great! I await the new designs :)

Comment: Good stuff !! But we do deserve it !!

Comment: My very important and valuable input: *Weeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee!*

Comment: Ana - just in case you hadn't followed NReilingh's link on Shevliaskovic's post below: looking good on consensus for a naming tweak for the site - http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/928/104

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I'm currently speaking with the rest of the community team to get a handle on what sort of considerations there are for site name changes. You can expect a meta post shortly.

Comment: @WheatWilliams: And you've done good! Keep up the good spirit :)

Comment: Well done! This great site does deserve a graduation. ☺☺

Answer (score 29):

Excellent news Ana,

As per Chris's comment, [some kind](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/104) of [music rendering](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/913/10938), probably a JS implementation of Lilypond, is likely to be required, although having a [basic set of musical characters](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/264/104) to include in questions may also be useful.

And we already have some [initial thoughts on a logo](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/92/104) - will need to be brought up to date etc.

We also reckon a [Music blog](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/679/104) will be very useful - this is a very subjective topic, and many interesting areas which wouldn't necessarily make it into a question/answer could be very useful to have on site.

Aside from that, I had a quick browse through the top 4 pages of meta questions and I can't see anything else that is critical (although anyone feel free to edit in any extras you think are important)

Comment: Good suggestions. We're aware of the Lilypond conversation and we'll follow up there soon. I would also encourage you to ponder questions of site governance or question quality -- if you have big picture thoughts about how this community works, this is an ideal opportunity to bring them up.

Comment: Good start @DrMayhem. Two other issues that we should probably think about is [jTab only being active on guitar tagged questions](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/240/guitar-tab-plugin-jtab-should-be-active-only-in-questions-tagged-guitar) and a [possible site name change](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/49/is-there-a-better-name-for-this-site). Also it would be nice if we as a site cleaned up the tags a bit before graduation.

Comment: Open question: should we re-run the site name "poll" question? It was almost three years between when it was first posted and when I came up with the second place answer, so it might be a good idea to get the current userships' opinion on the matter.

Comment: I'm still pretty new here, but looking over the suggested logos I didn't see anything that looks very professional. I might try my hand at something but I'm not much of a graphic artist, just a lover of clean UI. When does the vote on the new name get finalized?

Comment: A Javascript interpretation of Lilypond would be rather hard and put a lot of burden on the server. (Though the rendering is beautiful) An implementation of VexFlow would be easier to adapt (I've written an intermediary library, [music21j](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21j) that can make it easier to port to; it also adds sound playback via MIDI.js; since parsing MusicXML is possible via an external library, it'd allow for more software tools than just lilypond). But agreed, something to render.

Comment: Does this help with the lilypond integration? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Score

Answer (score 18):

There has been a long discussion with quite a few suggestions on the [name of the site](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/is-there-a-better-name-for-this-site).

I don't know if we can/will change it, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

---

I personally like the *Music: Theory & Practice* name.

Comment: I like that a lot! Because performance is a type of practice, and theory is neither, but we get a lot of music theory questions.

Comment: Hey folks! We decided to do another round of voting for the site name question -- see here: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/928/site-rename-poll-round-two

Comment: I like that better as well.  There are more theory questions than performance questions.

Comment: I like "Theory and Practice" because it is literary convention. Look up "Practice and Theory" on a book selling website, no results.  Only "Theory and Practice".  Why break this convention?  I'm open to the idea that there is a good reason, for example to emphasize Practice over Theory...is that the case?  Or to give Practice a different meaning than in books. If it's arbitrary, should have stuck to literary convention...

Answer (score 8):

I think the only governance/quality question that is currently not fully satisfied is around defining the scope.

At the one end, questions on specific songs may well be covered by the [Music Fans](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans) proposal, so we have been pointing folks in that direction. It's only halfway towards being fully committed though, but I think until then, we keep those sorts of questions out of scope.

We have more difficulty at the crossover between music and hardware - specifically around electronic music, where there may not be any real instruments, and DJ'ing, where there may not be any creation of music as such (yes - I know I'm probably wording that wrongly)
For these, I think the consensus is firmly that they are on topic, but getting clarity within our scope text is quite important.

Overall though, and our August site eval supports this, our quality is good and we are definitely going the right direction.

Comment: There is also much overlap on music programming questions w/ StackOverflow.  I think that they're valuable to allow on either forum since the differences in expertise to solve them can be subtle.

Comment: Overlap is inevitable and acceptable, I think. But I also think this site is *overloaded* by the way its scope is defined, which is why we have these issues.  Perhaps there is no getting around this: music is art, but a very cross-disciplinary one.  In computer science, the lines are thin but can be drawn.  If we could draw such lines in music, it would not be art.