# When is Music SE graduating?

Tags: support

We got the gladsome tidings three months ago but we're still in beta. When is Music SE graduating?  Is there something we need to do to make it happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I left a (playful) comment, but I realized this merits an answer. What Dr. Mayhem said is exactly right.

This site is already [lined up for graduation](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/925/music-se-is-graduating-congratulations).  However, our design team is facing some *serious* backlog and I expect we're still looking at a matter of months before they drop by and solicit feedback on mockups.

*Don't worry. Even if it continues to take awhile, you're still graduating.*

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing left to do from our side.

It is graduating, and the design team are on it, along with a few other sites.

A lot of Dev and design activities slow over Christmas, but we have been assured it is imminent.

Comment: I endorse this message.

Comment: Thanks for that, Ana :-)

Comment: Good luck ☺, i heard the progress is 98% now.